# Why won't promise resolve in a service?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a factory `NewEditSvc` where I'm trying to share functionality common to `NewCtrl` and `EditCtrl`.  One thing I'm trying to do is get `feeParameters` from the server inside the service but this is not working.

```
angular.module('feeSuitesApp')
.factory('NewEditSvc', function($q, FeeTypesSvc){
  var _feeParameters = {};

  function getParameters(){
    return _feeParameters;
  }

  function setParameters(feeType){
    var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject){
      FeeTypesSvc.resource.get({id: feeType.id, association: 'fee_parameters'}).
      $promise.then(function(data){
        resolve(data);
      }, function(error){
        reject(error);
      })
    });

    promise.then(function(data){
      _feeParameters = data.master;
    });
  }

  return {
    getParameters: getParameters,
    setParameters: setParameters
  }
});

angular.module('feeSuitesApp')
.controller('NewCtrl', function(NewEditSvc, feeType){
  $scope.feeParameters = NewEditSvc.getParameters();
  $scope.feeType = feeType;
  $scope.setParameters = function(feeType){
    NewEditSvc.setParameters(feeType);
  };
  $scope.setParameters($scope.feeType);
});
```

After my last line `$scope.feeParameters` is not set.  But if I return the `promise` variable from NewEditSvc.setParameters() and then in my `NewCtrl` I do the following:

```
  var promise = $scope.setParameters($scope.feeType);

  promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.feeParameters = data.master;
  });
```

Then everything works.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the explicit-construction anti-pattern as discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23803744/548997).

Comment: I'm guessing I don't need $q.  But still, am not able to resolve the promise within the service itself and to return the value to the controller.

Comment: The point of that anti-pattern answer is that you shouldn't be resolving the promise in the service - you should be returning the promise and handling the resolving in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you're not returning your promise in setParameters. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q/

Just add `return promise`.